# In C#, how to transform two methods with different numbers and types of arguments into one?

Tags: c#

I have two methods that almost identical, how to transform these methods into the one method?

```
GetJobInfoByStatus(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    var searchParameter = new BackgroundJobSearchParameters();
    return _jobInfoRetriever.GetMatchingJobs(searchParameter);
}

GetJobInfoByJobType(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, BackgroundJobType jobType)
{
    var searchParameter = new BackgroundJobSearchParameters
    {
        JobTypes = new BackgroundJobTypeCollection { jobType }
    };

    return _jobInfoRetriever.GetMatchingJobs(searchParameter);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Have you tried anything to solve this problem? If so, please show us your code and explain where you got stuck.

Comment: What is the type of BackgroundJobType? Is it an Enum? (all the answers below don't work with an Enum)

Comment: Yes, BackgroundJobType - enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try set an optional parameter for `BackgroundJobType`. Then check for null in the object initialization, if non-null, set it.

```
private IList<BackgroundJobInfo> GetJobInfoByJobType(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, BackgroundJobType jobType = null)
{
    var searchParameter = new BackgroundJobSearchParameters
    {
        MinStartTime = startTime,
        MaxStartTime = endTime,
        JobStatusFlags = JobStatusFlags.Failed | JobStatusFlags.Succeeded,
        JobTypes = jobType != null ? new BackgroundJobTypeCollection { jobType } : null
    };

    return _backgroundJobInfoRetriever.GetMatchingJobs(searchParameter)
                 .Select(x => _backgroundJobsProvider.GetInfoById(x.Id))
                 .ToList();
}
```

Edit: Didn't know `BackgroundJobType` is an `enum` type.

What I suggest is have a "Default" value built into your enum, like this:

```
enum BackgroundJobType
{
    Default = 0,
    JobType1 = 1,
    JobType2 = 2,
    JobType3 = 3
}
```

Then instead of a null value, set the optional parameter to

```
private IList<BackgroundJobInfo> GetJobInfoByJobType(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, BackgroundJobType jobType = BackgroundJobType.Default)
```

Then

```
JobTypes = (jobType != BackgroundJobType.Default) ?
               new BackgroundJobTypeCollection { jobType } : null
```

Comment: even if BackgroundJobType has enum type?

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[OPTIONAL Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)**

`Optional arguments` enable you to omit arguments for some parameters.

```
private IList<BackgroundJobInfo> GetJobInfoByJobType(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime, BackgroundJobType jobType = null)
{

    If (jobType == null)
    {
        var searchParameter = new BackgroundJobSearchParameters
        {
        MinStartTime = startTime,
        MaxStartTime = endTime,
        JobStatusFlags = JobStatusFlags.Failed | JobStatusFlags.Succeeded
        };
    }
    else
    {
        var searchParameter = new BackgroundJobSearchParameters
        {
        MinStartTime = startTime,
        MaxStartTime = endTime,
        JobStatusFlags = JobStatusFlags.Failed | JobStatusFlags.Succeeded,
        JobTypes = new BackgroundJobTypeCollection { jobType }
        };
    }    

    return _backgroundJobInfoRetriever.GetMatchingJobs(searchParameter)
                                    .Select(x => _backgroundJobsProvider.GetInfoById(x.Id))
                                    .ToList();
}
```